# Custo Signup Page

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

### Background Information:

I have been following `admin-on-rest` example to create my custom Admin app. I created a custom component that is pretty much the same as https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/Login.js

However I want to provide the functionality for users to signup within the application, so I added a Sign Up button, that we clicked will redirect to `domain.com/signup`

### Problem:

After reading the [Authentication docs](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html) and trying it out myself, I found that on each route change the event `AUTH_CHECK` is evaluated. However, in input `params` I get as resource something I already defined in my `<Admin>` component. Basically, I need a way to "whitelist" a path and allow users to navigate to that path without them being authenticated.

### Questions:

Is there a way to create a custom signup page and whitelist the path "/signup" so that authentication is not checked?

Is this something I need to implement with custom `React Router` routes, or is it something at the `authClient` level?

Has anyone tried to add a new signup page, and how did you make it work?

Comment: I have created an app with login, signup and password forget. It uses a custom restClient to handle the signup and forgotpassword requests and route them. With a custom saga (addon to the authentication saga) I call these authClient types. It does not have a different url like /register/ as you suggest, but the register and forgot pass form are conditionally visible on the login page. You can directly call the register form using a parameter, in my case it is /#/login?show=register. If you are interested in this, let me know and I'll work out a demo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you help me with a demo? I'm not sure how to make the router "know" that only that path should not be checked. I would really appreciate it! EDIT: I understand a little bit better now after reading your comment again. So you are saying that you never change the URL in the browser. That is a great idea, if you don't mind sharing the saga that would be amazing!

Comment: Hi, I will try to lookup my solution one of these days. Is a little while ago I created this, but I still use it live and it works great.